# her/him or she/he?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Reading the news last week one sentence jumped out at me and has been bothering me since:

> When Tommy Thompson and his longtime companion did leave the hotel room, usually alone and **her more than him**, they would use a combination of buses, taxis and walking around to shake anyone who might be tailing them.

Original article, second paragraph, here: [Link to CBC](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/tommy-thompson-florida-treasure-hunter-faces-accusations-over-missing-gold-1.2936403#vf-7446300000903)

HER left the hotel more than HIM?

While **her more than him** is certainly used - especially in N.America - more often than  **she more than he**, surely she/he here is actually correct?

I've searched Google for "he/she vs her/him" and found many pages discussing this but nothing which will definitively set my mind at ease.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a separate clause, instead of expanding the sentence out as:

> When Tommy Thompson and his longtime companion did leave the hotel room, usually alone and *her left the hotel more than him*, they would use a combination of buses

Think of it as:

> When Tommy Thompson and his longtime companion did leave the hotel room, they would use a combination of buses. Usually alone and her more than him.

This is a verbless clause, which means it shouldn't have a subject (he/she).